# Could Careers offer filters for both employers and candidates interested only in contract work?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I know that Careers is very much aimed at people looking for permanent work, but it seems to me like it could be fantastic for contractors and for companies that employ them. All contractors have nightmare stories about recruitment agencies, all companies that employ contractors or ever have employed contractors get constant hassle from recruitment agents badgering them to take on more contractors. If Careers could cut out the agent layer between employers and contractors it would improve the lives of people on both sides endlessly, although it would be bad news for recruitment agents and BMW garages. I think I can contain my pity.

Are there any plans to bring any contractor-oriented functionality into Careers?

It would be great if an employer adding a job could check a box to mark it as contract work, and for candidates to filter their search results down to only contract positions. Similarly, a candidate should be able to indicate on their profile that they are interested in contract work, and employers should be able to filter candidate search to view only those interested in being contractors.

Comment: I am bit confusing about your qiz. As my suggest, the specialization should be with the work which has to do, but not for the specific contractor.

Comment: As someone who contracted for a long time and who got several contracting jobs through Careers, I am not sure what exactly you are looking for here.

Comment: What contractor-oriented functionality would you like to see added?

Comment: Is there anything preventing clients from finding contractors directly through Careers? I would assume that the high number of recruitment agents using it is just because most companies farm out the job of looking for people to recruitment agents.

Comment: @Quentin There isn't anything preventing it, but there also isn't anything to make it easy if that is one's preference. It's somewhere that the site feels to me as though it could be sharpened up a little.

Comment: I edited this question to reflect what seems to be the actual *functionality* you want. If that's not accurate, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: @Laura good edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This is now live as of 11th December.

We recently started asking employers to tell us if their job is Permanent or Contract when they submit a job listing.

Now we have the data, we've turned on the search filter, so you can restrict your search to "permanent", "contract", or "any job type".

[image: Filtering by job type]

Comment: Excellent. I think the difference between employee/contractor varies between different countries - some people view contracting as just a temporary job but in the UK for instance it is an entirely separate career path and employers are normally pretty definite which they want for any role.

Comment: I'm in France and don't see that in French version of site. It says "CDI à temps plein" (regular job), "CDD" (fixed-term job). There's also an option "télétravail" (work from home) but it seems just a flag for the first two, "stage ou formation en alternance" (internship or work-and-training).  These terms appear both when setting one's personal profile, and when a recruiter looks for candidates. What about other languages/countries ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused as to what exactly you are asking. Right now, you can always create a profile and set it to say you are only interested in Contract work.

Comment: Maybe. But Careers does not advertise in any way that contract work is a thing there. The impression that Careers gives right now is that it is a place for permanent jobs. There are no filtering options whatsoever that take contractor work into consideration - the only distinction in work models is full time vs. Part time.

Comment: @Pëkka I don't think we make a distinction either way. Customers are free to post contract jobs. The only thing I will admit is that we don't have an option when creating a listing to make it explicitly a contract position.

Comment: Sure, they are free to post them, but if potential contractors feel Careers.SE is a place for full-time jobs, what good does it do? Everything on the site right now - the name, the UI - is skewed towards permanent jobs and that's what the popular perception is.  Adding "contract job" as an option in searches and forms would go a long way.

Comment: I am totally with @Pëkka on this one- it would be a small change that would make the site much easier to use as a contractor or a company that uses contractors.